# Print lines containing at least all vowels in any order but no consecutives

Tags: shell-script, grep

The problem is to write a script that takes a file as argument and prints all the lines that contain -at least- all the vowels , -regardless of ordering-, but with [**no two same consecutive vowels**].

e.g aeaiou is allowed, but not aaeiou because of the 'aa'

The script below is almost what I need, but it does not check for consecutiveness.

```
egrep -i '.[a]+' ${1} | egrep -i '[e]+' | egrep -i '[i]+' | egrep -i '[o]+'| egrep -i '[u]+'
```

Note: I am allowed to use grep and looping constructs, but no obscur/high-level commands.

solved;

```
egrep -vi '[a][a]' ${1} | egrep -vi '[e][e]' | egrep -vi '[i][i]' | egrep -vi '[o][o]' | egrep -vi '[i][i]' | egrep -i '[a]+' | egrep -i '[e]+' | egrep -i '[i]+' | egrep -i '[o]+'| egrep -i '[u]+'
```

Comment: this is rather a programming question, this belongs to stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry, but how do people even *get* problems like these?

Comment: Also, vowel is connected to sounds, not letters.

Comment: Y is both a vowel and a consonant.

Comment: @Kusalananda Is it too easy or too hard?

Comment: it does not matter if it is easy, we are not answering programming questions.

Comment: It's just a very odd problem to have, that's all.

Comment: This is on-topic here.  It's about unix commands and shell scripting, which are both accepted.

Comment: The answer should go as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: It is on-topic.  It smells like homework, but, since the user has partially solved it (and presented his partial solution), it should stay open. (Unless it's a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you want to exclude the entire line if there are double vowels, this should work:

```
grep -i a file | \
    grep -i e | \
    grep -i i | \
    grep -i o | \
    grep -i u | \
    grep -v -i '\([aeiou]\)\1'
```

Comment: last line: why escape the parentheses and also why put parentheses in the first place?

Comment: @HeheNewUser Escape parentheses: that's `grep(1)` syntax (as opposed to `egrep(1)`).  Why put parentheses in the first place: `\(..\)\1` means two copies of what's between parentheses.  It matches `aa` and `ee`, but not `ae`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking `grep` several times, you could also use a single invocation of `sed`, either

```
sed -rn '/(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)/d; /a/{/e/{/i/{/o/{/u/p}}}}'
```

or

```
sed -rn '/([aeiou])\1/d; /a/{/e/{/i/{/o/{/u/p}}}}'
```

if you prefer to use back-references.

Answer (score 0):

Using your question (slightly modified, with a line-break before the `but not aaeiou because of the 'aa'`) as input:

```
$ cat hehe.txt
The problem is to write a script that takes a file as argument
and prints all the lines that contain -at least- all the vowels ,
-regardless of ordering-, but with [no two same consecutive vowels].

e.g aeaiou is allowed, 
but not aaeiou because of the 'aa'

The script below is almost what I need, but it does not check for
consecutiveness.

$ awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 };
       ! /aa|ee|ii|oo|uu/ && ( /a/ && /e/ && /i/ && /o/ && /u/ )' hehe.txt
The problem is to write a script that takes a file as argument
-regardless of ordering-, but with [no two same consecutive vowels].
e.g aeaiou is allowed,
```

The `awk` script enables case-insensitive mode, removes lines containing double-vowels and then prints lines containing at least one of each vowel.