# Need a hand with grep + regex

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression

I need to find set of words that contain vowels occurring in aeiou order.No need to occur consecutively. Also allowing each vowel to occur multiple times before the occurence of the next, but never occurring again after the next vowel has occurred

basic input list - https://jsfiddle.net/3mj72nwh/

so far I used these regex

```
grep 'a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeiu]*u[^aeio]*' words2.txt - this is the closest one that I got

grep 'a[^e^i^o^u]*e[^a^i^o^u]*i[^a^e^o^u]*o[^a^e^i^u]*u[^a^e^i^o]*' words2.txt

grep 'a.*e[^a]*i[^ae]*o[^aei]*u[^aeio]*' words2.txt
```

And some outputs from first one -

```
appenditious,appetitious,arenicolous,arreptitious,arsenious

....

ultraexpeditious,ultrareligious,unfacetious
```

most of my outputs will satisfied the conditions but some of them are not. e.g. - ***ultraexpeditious*** because when ***u*** occurs after that there cannot be have any vowel in the word.

Comment: or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292247/bash-print-lines-containing-at-least-all-vowels-in-any-order-but-no-consecutiv

Comment: still I have that same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to anchor your search (or use `-x`):

```
grep -x '[^aeiou]*a[^eiou]*e[^aiou]*i[^aeou]*o[^aeiu]*u[^aeio]*'
```

`ultraexpeditious` matches because it contains `aexpeditious` which is matched by your regexp.